# Calculating cross product w of u and v

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

[image]

2 problems:

does it mean we have to find cross product of uxv and then name it w??

if yes in c) will the answer be (uxv).w? (ans 42)

Comment: Yes, $w$ is the name given to the cross-product of $u$ and $v$. This vector is given a name because it is referred to in part (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

1. $$w = u \times v = (-3,-1,2) \times (-2,-2,3) $$
2. $$ n = w / \| w \| $$
3. $$ V = | w\cdot(u \times v) | $$